# How to get a value from a JQGrid? - on HTML5 Builder

Tags: php, javascript, html, jqgrid, html5builder

Sorry for this question - I know that there are a lot of posts talking about this, but none about how to do it on HTML5 builder.

So, I want to get the value of my Column "ID" (that is the last one of my 4 columns), from the row that the user selected.

Because i'm a newbie here, I tryed something like this:

```
$a=$this->jqgrid1->getCell($this->jqgrid1->rowid,3);
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JqGrid::getCell() in C:\docs\ .... etc
```

So, did someone worked with this JQGrid on HTML5 Builder already, and found a way to get the cells content? By the way, I'm connecting the JQGrid to a Datasource, which leads to a MYsql Database. Maybe if I could get only the rownumber, i could do a cycle with datasource->next() untill it reaches the rownumber.

Hope you can give me some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.embarcadero.com/messageview.jspa?messageID=580784&stqc=true

Here is the Answer.

2 days, 0 answers.